# Регулярное выражение для подстановки mailto: PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Привет.

Не могу разобраться с регуляркой. Ее задача - парсить текст и заменять попавшиеся email адреса ссылками mailto:

```
$text = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([\w0-9&\-_.]+?)@([\w\-]+\.([\w\-\.]+\.)*[\w]+)#iu", "\\1<a href=\"mailto:\\2@\\3\">\\2@\\3</a>", $text);
```

Все работает, только когда перед адресом есть какие-нибудь символы. Например:

test@test.com - не работает.

test test@test.com - работает.

**UPD:** Дело оказалось в том, что предварительный фильтр строки добавляет в нее `<p>` вначале. Я не очень силен в регулярках, поэтому дополнительно поинтересуюсь, является ли такое решение проблемы нормальным:

```
(^|>|[\n ])([\w0-9&\-_.]+?)@([\w\-]+\.([\w\-\.]+\.)*[\w]+)
```

Comment: @silent-box, нужно больше информации.  
На примере какого текста проверяли?  

**[Ваш пример работает][1]**


  [1]: http://ideone.com/y3m5pT

Comment: Пример текста, на котором не работает эта замена, приведите, пожалуйста.

[ideone.com][1]


  [1]: http://ideone.com/TzzTf1

Comment: `"#^([\n\s]*)([\w&\-_\.]+?)@([\w\-]+\.([\w\-\.]+\.)*\w+)#iu"`

Comment: Да, в онлайн-сервисах действительно работает. Значит проблема у меня в другом месте, а не в регулярке. Спасибо! Буду разбираться.
___

Действительно, дело оказалось в том, что предварительно это дело пропускается через фильтр, добавляющий <p> перед строкой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо:

```
(^|[\n ])
```

лучше использовать:

```
\b
```

После собаки у тебя используется "*\w*", которое включает и "*_*", чего в доменах нет.
Попробуй что-нибудь попроще, например так:

```
\b([\w-]+@[a-z0-9-.]+)\b
```

А вообще, есть тонны готовых регулярок в сети.

Comment: Спасибо, учту!

А что скажите на счет учета <p> в начале строки? (отписался в конце самого вопроса)
Нормально будет написать (\b|<p>)?

Comment: Почитай про значение \b, всё поймешь.